# Retrieve custom post by a query on one of its custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I've been using custom posts on my website, among them there are : "session" and "lecture".

The custom post "lecture" has many custom fields such "title", "duration"...

The custom post "session" has many custom fields too, one of them is "session_lecture" that points to a lecture : hence, a session is linked to a lecture. The lecture is chosen in a dropdown menu, generated with a nice tool : cmb2 metaboxes.

I handle the display of a session and a lecture with filters, like :

```
add_filter('the_content','add_session_content');
```

Those filters retrieve the custom fields and display them the way I want.

I'd like, for each lecture, to display a list of sessions that provide this lecture. So, within the filter above, I have written :

```
$args = array(

            'post_type' => 'session',
            'meta_key'     => 'session_lecture',
            'meta_value'   => '$id', //$id is the id of the current lecture
            'meta_compare' => '=',

            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                the_content();
            endwhile;
```

But the query seems to return nothing. What's wrong with my query ? Should I use another mechanism ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I removed : `'meta_compare' => '='` !